# Don't show textbox message when access from another class

Tags: c#, winforms

I have following code

```
namespace Spaceship_Invaders
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        public class spaceship
        {

            Form1 myform = new Form1();           

            public void mspaceship()
            {              
                myform.textBox1.Text = " working";               


            }
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            spaceship myspaceship = new spaceship();
            myspaceship.mspaceship();

        }


    }
}
```

When I click on the button textbox1 don't show anything. Please tell me what I am missing here.

Comment: Just an observation about best practice, which will help others better understand your code. Your `spaceship` classname should really be `Spaceship`. Classes should start with an uppercase character. This makes it easier to differentiate Classes and their instances.

Comment: you've got your design a bit messed up. Spaceship should not be responisble for filling the text in a textbox. The form itself should fill the text in the textbox, that is provided by the spaceship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the text on a different form instance than the one you are displaying. The `spaceship` class creates a new form here:

```
Form1 myform = new Form1();
```

And continues to use that. This is not the visible form, so you can't see the effect.

You need to pass in the `Form1` instance for this to work, and `spaceship` should probably take this as a constructor parameter. You can get the reference to the current instance in an instance method using the `this` keyword. A working example would be:

```
public class spaceship
{
    public spaceship(Form1 form)
    {
        myForm = form;
    }

    Form1 myform;

    public void mspaceship()
    {              
        myform.textBox1.Text = " working";               


    }
}

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    spaceship myspaceship = new spaceship(this);
    myspaceship.mspaceship();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass on the `Form` as a variable and store it on your Spaceship class.

```
public class Spaceship
{ 
     Form1 _form;       
     public Spaceship(Form1 myform)
     {
        _form = myform;
     }   

     public void mspaceship()
     {              
          _form.textBox1.Text = " working";                
     }
}
```

Then in button pass on the current class:

```
Spaceship myspaceship = new Spaceship(this);
myspaceship.mspaceship();
```

Personally I would probably do something like this using [Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx).

```
 public class Spaceship
 { 
      public String Name { get; set; }     
      public Spaceship(string name)
      {
         Name = name;
      }   
 }
```

Inside the button you use the following.

```
Spaceship spaceship = Spaceship("Enterprise");
this.textBox1.Text = spaceship.Name;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for nice answer. I have seen in many code to use "_" like you used _form. What does it mean?

Comment: It is referring to the variable being private. Private means that the variable cannot be accessed outside the class.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest changing your design a bit, so each class has it's own responsibility:

```
namespace Spaceship_Invaders
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Spaceship _myspaceship;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _myspaceship = new spaceship();
            this.textBox1.Text = myspaceship.mspaceship();
        }
    }

    public class Spaceship
    {
        public string mspaceship()
        {              
            return " working";               
        }
    }
}
```